# How is Ruby more object-oriented than Python?

Tags: python, ruby, oop

Matz, who invented Ruby, said that he designed the language to be more object-oriented than Python. How is Ruby more object-oriented than Python?

Answer (score 23):

If you take the Python from 1993 and compare it with Ruby then the latter is more object oriented. However, after the [overhaul in Python 2.2](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/new-style-classes.html) this is no longer true. I'd say that modern Python is as object oriented as it gets.

Comment: +1. This is very important. Matz announced Ruby on February, 23, 1993. His survey of existing languages that led him to start working on Ruby would obviosuly have been even before that. So, you have to take historical context into account, you can't just compare with Python 3.2, you need to look at whatever the widely available version was in 1992/93. Also, you have to take "cultural" context into account: matz is very familiar with Smalltalk. Anybody who has ever used Smalltalk usually has much stronger views on OO than people who haven't. E.g. Alan Kay says that all state must be private.

Answer (score 18):

One example that's commonly given is `len`, which in Python is a built-in function. You may implement a special `__len__` method in your objects which will be called by `len`, but `len` is still a function. In Ruby, objects just have the `.length` property/method so it appears more object oriented when you say `obj.length` rather than `len(obj)` although deep under the hood pretty much the same thing happens.

That said, over the years Python have moved towards more object-orientation. Currently all objects (and implicitly user-defined objects) inherit from the `object` class. Meta-classes have also been added, and many of the built-in and core library classes have been organized into hierarchies with the help of ABCs (Abstract Base Classes).

In my heavy usage of Python I have never found it lacking in the OO department. It can do everything I want it to do with objects. True, Ruby *feels* somewhat more purely OO, but at least in my experience this hasn't been a really practical concern.

Comment: I find the 'len' example misleading. In that sense operator overloading is not object oriented either, because `a + b` does not look like a method call. The important thing is that it gets implemented as a method.

Comment: @nikow: the point is that `len` is an actual function. Operator overloading is just syntactic sugar - the compiler actually generates a method call. This is not the case with Python's `len`

Comment: As you wrote yourself `len` generally calls the `__len__` method. Having `len` as a function is syntactic sugar, just like operator overloading.

Comment: @nikow: I still insist it's subtly different. If you disassemble some Python code that uses `len` you'll see an *actual call* to a function. True, this function will find `__len__` (after a couple of levels of indirection, by the way).

Answer (score 12):

From [WikiVS](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Python_vs_Ruby),

> … where in Ruby all functions and most operators are in fact methods of an object, a number of Python functions are procedural functions rather than methods.

The following [interview](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2001/11/29/ruby.html) with Matz, the creator of Ruby, provides additional context to your question and the point above.

> …
>
> **Stewart**: Let's start with a little history. Why did you decide to write Ruby?
>
> **Matz**: Back in 1993, I was talking with a colleague about scripting languages. I was pretty impressed by their power and their possibilities. I felt scripting was the way to go.
>
> As a long time object-oriented programming fan, it seemed to me that OO programming was very suitable for scripting too. Then I looked around the Net. I found that Perl 5, which had not released yet, was going to implement OO features, but it was not really what I wanted. I gave up on Perl as an object-oriented scripting language.
>
> Then I came across Python. It was an interpretive, object-oriented language. But I didn't feel like it was a "scripting" language. In addition, it was a hybrid language of procedural programming and object-oriented programming.
>
> I wanted a scripting language that was more powerful than Perl, *and more object-oriented than Python*. That's why I decided to design my own language.
>
> …

Comment: *A number of Python functions are procedural*: I assume this means functions such as `len` or `<`; those are implemented as methods (`__len__` and `__lt__` respectively).

Answer (score -2):

It's simple, **nearly everything** in Ruby (including numbers) is an object; there are no scalar values.

Comment: @Beau, AFAIK, in python, you cannot inject your functions into the built-in classes (Integer,String)...so by that respect, Ruby is more OOP.

Comment: @st0le: I don't think this makes Ruby _more_ object oriented. Just because Ruby can re-open all classes to add more methods is not (IMHO) a measure of OO-ness. Java cannot "add methods to classes". [Can't believe I ever used Java as an exemplar!]. Being able to Monkey-Patch/Duck-Punch is more about dynamism than OO-ness.

Comment: Ruby is not more OOP because it can monkey patch classes (I agree it's more about dynamism), but because it was designed from the ground up to be a pure OOP language; everything is an object.

Comment: Same for modern Python, everything is an object.